# ways to include miscellaneous symbols like Recycle, Rain on the ZPL files for printing labels

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am new to ZPL coding and am not sure how to include miscellaneous symbols like Recycle, Rain on the ZPL files for printing labels.

I tried a bit of coding in UTF-8 encoding by using ^CI28 command and converted the recycle and rain logos to hexadecimal and tried escaping the default underscores using ^FH command but no avail.

```
^XA
^CI28
^CFT,30,30
^FO50,50^FH^FDTesting^FS
^FO50,100^FH^FD_e2_99_b2^FS
^XZ
```

In UTF-16, it is printing &72 instead of recycle logo

```
^XA
^CI29
^CFT,30,30
^FO50,50^FH^FDTesting^FS
^FO50,100^FH^FD_2672^FS
^XZ
```

Also the results i checked are from simulator available in http://labelary.com/viewer.html. Not sure if there is an issue with my code or simulator in which i am seeing the output.It will be great if any ZPL coding experts can provide some pointers on this regard. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Zebra printers have extremely limited character sets.  You need to download to the printer a font that contains the characters you want to print.  Alternatively, create PNG images of the characters and download the images.  With the images, you can embed them directly in the ZPL using the ^GF command, or store them to the printer using ~DY.

Answer (score 0):

Store the images on the printer's memory, and call them up as you need them with the image command.